# How to check if cookies have changed in react?

Tags: reactjs, cookies

My system has a layout that has a number of components (two menus and the container)
When I want to change them according to the cookies.

And I understand that this should be done in the main component and send props to the children.

The problem is, I can not make it happen. I tried to do the following code-

```
     componentDidMount () {
         this.checkTimer = setInterval (
             () => this.tick (),
             1000
         );
       
     }

 tick () {
 axios.post(`api/UserDetails?code=${this.state.cookies}`)
                 .then ((user) => {
                     const persons = user.data;
                     this.setState ({userDetails: persons});
                     console.log (user.data)
                 }
                 );
         }
```

But this is only done if there are cookies when loading the page. But it is not affected if the cookie changes in another component.

What line of code needs to be done to check if the cookie has changed?

Regards

Comment: What version of React are you using? Most people I know (including myself) use functional components, and the lifecycle hooks make it *extremely* easy to look for changes in state. It'd be a useEffect() hook with a dependency on the value that you expect to change. Just a thought.

Comment: @JoelHager I use class so I use componentDidMount ()

Comment: I get that, but the functional approach is essentially the de facto standard, and the intelligent state management would essentially be a one-liner in a functional component. Is there a particular reason you're using a class component over a functional one?

Comment: @JoelHager Honestly not, if it's better I can change .. but there is no solution for class?